# replace all \0 in command ouput with \n AND a trailing \n

Tags: bash, sed

```
git diff -z --name-only origin/master...<sha>
```

gives output files separated by `NUL` (I need the `-z` option)

I want all files to be separated by new line so I pipe into sed

```
git diff -z --name-only origin/master...<sha> | sed s/\0/\\n/g
```

but I need a trailing newline. Is the best way to append a `NUL` before sed? or append a `\n` afterward? Or better does sed have option append trailing newline?

Comment: | xargs -0 printf '%s\n'

Comment: They're NUL separated because you added `-z`. Simply remove that to get the default linefeed separated output

Comment: `| tr '\0' '\n'`

Comment: Use 'git ... | sed ... ; echo ` to get a trailing new line

Comment: @thatotherguy I should have clarify. I need the -z option so file with special characters in it don't get quoted.

Comment: I am curious whether `s/$/\n/` or `$s/$/\n/` would do it in sed... or maybe `sed -z 's/$/\n'` would do the trailing newline even without a trailing null.